# Pattern matcher returns unexpected values

Tags: java, regex

could you take a look at the pattern (java) in the below result. 
I expect the result should give me 3 group value, but instead it gave me 2 values only
I think i missed something.

```java
package com.mycompany.testapp;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 *
 * @author bo17a
 */
public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Pattern mPattern = Pattern.compile("^love (.*?) way you (.*?)$");
        Matcher matcher = mPattern.matcher("love the way you lie");
        if(matcher.find()){
            String[] match_groups = new String[matcher.groupCount()];
            System.out.println(String.format("groupCount: %d", matcher.groupCount()));
            for(int j = 0;j<matcher.groupCount();j++){
                System.out.println(String.format("j %d",j));
                match_groups[j] = matcher.group(j);
                System.out.println(match_groups[j]);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The result I got is:

```
2
love the way you lie
the
```

but my expected result should be:

```
3
love the way you lie
the
lie
```

**update** 
i tried to add up one number of group as suggested in replies:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.mycompany.testapp;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 *
 * @author lee
 */
public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Pattern mPattern = Pattern.compile("^love (.*?) way you (.*?)$");
        Matcher matcher = mPattern.matcher("love the way you lie");
        if(matcher.find()){
            String[] match_groups = new String[matcher.groupCount()];
                System.out.println(String.format("groupCount: %d", matcher.groupCount()));
                for(int j = 0;j<=matcher.groupCount();j++){
                    System.out.println(String.format("j %d",j));
                    match_groups[j] = matcher.group(j);
                    System.out.println(match_groups[j]);
                }
        }
    }

}
```

The result is different from yours:

```
groupCount: 2
j 0
love the way you lie
j 1
the
j 2
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at com.mycompany.testapp.NewClass.main(NewClass.java:24)
Command execution failed.
```

I have tried on windows 10 JDK 8 Mac OS JDK 8. So, could this be a bug in Java, because you and I have different result for the same code?

**update 2**
Thank you friends,
I found my mistake. The problem is: groupCount return the number of group match (except for the whole string match). So the correct code should be

```
String[] match_groups = new String[matcher.groupCount()+1];
System.out.println(String.format("groupCount: %d", matcher.groupCount()));
for(int j = 0;j<=matcher.groupCount();j++){
    System.out.println(String.format("j %d",j));
    match_groups[j] = matcher.group(j);
    System.out.println(match_groups[j]);
}
```

Comment: @bipll, the first group is the whole string match, when we don't put any group in the pattern, the groupCount returns 1 (to shows that the pattern matches the string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that, you wish to also capture the full match as a group,

```
^(love (.*?) way you (.*?))$
```

Or just add 1 to your counter:

#### Test 1

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class RegularExpression{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Pattern mPattern = Pattern.compile("^love (.*?) way you (.*?)$");
        Matcher matcher = mPattern.matcher("love the way you lie");
        if(matcher.find()){
            String[] match_groups = new String[matcher.groupCount() + 1];
                System.out.println(String.format("groupCount: %d", matcher.groupCount() + 1));
                for(int j = 0;j<matcher.groupCount() + 1;j++){
                    System.out.println(String.format("j %d",j));
                    match_groups[j] = matcher.group(j);
                    System.out.println(match_groups[j]);
                }
        }

    }
}
```

#### Output

```
groupCount: 3
j 0
love the way you lie
j 1
the
j 2
lie
```

#### Test 2

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class RegularExpression{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        final String regex = "^(love (.*?) way you (.*?))$";
        final String string = "love the way you lie";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.DOTALL);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
            for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

#### Output

```
Full match: love the way you lie
Group 1: love the way you lie
Group 2: the
Group 3: lie
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: [^(love (.*?) way you (.*?))$](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(love%20(.*%3F)%20way%20you%20(.*%3F))%24) Regex Visualizer

Comment: @Emma here is the result
```
groupCount: 3
j 0
love the way you lie
j 1
love the way you lie
j 2
the
```
I want to catch the "lie" group

Comment: @Emma i use netbeans IDE 11 with JDK8. which IDE and java version you use?

Comment: @Emma interesting result, so original pattern ```^(love (.*?) way you (.*?))$``` doesn't match the "lie" but the matched the whole string. Strange!

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, `matcher.groupCount()` returns 2 in your case, so you only construct array of two strings and copy groups with numbers less than 2 into it, which are group 0 (the whole string) and group 1 ("the"). If you add 1 to `matcher.groupCount()` throughout your whole code, it works as expected.

Comment: Hi bipll, i tried to change 
`for(int j = 0;j<matcher.groupCount();j++){` to `for(int j = 0;j<=matcher.groupCount();j++){` but this error appears: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2`

Comment: Yes, you haven't changed the array size when allocating `matchGroups` so naturally it ran out of bounds. Have you noticed that _throughout your whole code_ part in my answer?

Comment: thank you my friend!! you are right, I found the mistake